# Wordpress: Jquery for theme and admin conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conflict

May there is very simple solution but I am facing issue to solve this as new to these all.

I am enqueue jquery and other script from my theme function php file. Below is my code

```
function mediaplus_scripts() {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        }

        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'listgrid-cookie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/list-grid/cookie.js', 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'listgrid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/list-grid/listgrid.js', 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'slider-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'home-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slides.min.jquery.js', 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'home-ajax-content', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dynamic-page/dynamicpage.js', 'jquery' );

        /* wp_enqueue_script( 'mediaplus-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', 'jquery' ); */ 

    } 
    add_action('init', 'mediaplus_scripts');

    function add_admin_scripts() {

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'mediaplus_options', 'http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js', 'jquery' );

    }
    add_action('init', 'add_admin_scripts');
```

Problem with the code is admin enqueue function is conflicting with theme function and resulting disabling all javascript in theme only admin jquery is working.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It's almost impossible to solve this without knowing the inventory and order of other scripts in the page and seeing errors thrown in a console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of your problem is in the add_action.

add_action('**wp_enqueue_scripts**', 'mediaplus_scripts');

instead of

add_action('init', 'mediaplus_scripts');

The **wp_enqueue_scripts** is used for the front-end and **admin_enqueue_scripts** for the admin. The **init** action is called for both.

I had the same problem and thanks to john for the link ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot 1000 times :) you at lest give me the real reason and solution..thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are having trouble because you are de-registering the default jQuery library that WordPress ships with (which use noConflict mode) and then replacing it with the Google CDN version (which doesn't use noConflict mode)

You should take a look at this post on wp-tuts which is really helpful for understanding the wp_enqueue functions and best practices for using them: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/